# How to Query Azure App Service AppServiceHTTPLogs for Source IP, Target IP, and URL Name?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring, azure-appservice

I'm working with an Azure App Service, and I need to monitor and analyze HTTP traffic.
I want to retrieve **the source IP, target IP, and URL name** from the AppServiceHTTPLogs table. However, I'm not quite sure how to construct the query for this specific information.

Can someone provide an example query for querying the AppServiceHTTPLogs table in Azure Monitor to extract the source IP, target IP, and URL name from HTTP logs?

Example : I'm trying to Total Time Taken For  API requests from a specific source (let's call it A) to a specific target (let's call it B) within a defined time period. However, I'm having trouble constructing the appropriate query for this task

Comment: What is the result you are getting when you query direct `AppServiceHTTPLogs` ?

Comment: Total Time Taken For Request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an  query to  extract your data and also to  calculate the total time taken for  requests from a specific source to a specific target within  time period (replace A and B with the actual source and target IP addresses):

**Complete Logs**
[image]

Query to  retrieve **the source IP, target IP(SPort), and URL name** from the AppServiceHTTPLogs table

```
AppServiceHTTPLogs
| where CIp == "127.0.0.1" and SPort == "443"
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1d)
| project CIp, SPort, CsUriQuery, TimeTaken
| summarize TotalTimeTaken = sum(TimeTaken) by CIp, SPort, CsUriQuery
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Why do we need a port number for the destination? I want to establish a connection from A to B, where A's IP is 123.323.32 and B's IP is 323.32.3.3. i don't have idea about why we get consider port as destination. i need destinaion consider as my destination ip